# At commands with E3531, sms disappears after one second

Tags: sms, at-command, huawei-mobile-services

I'm using the `AT` commands with the dongle. I activated the `ttyUSB[0-2]` based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/491963/269279) and as follows `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1f01`:

```
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x1f01    
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Now, I set my device as follows:

```
AT+CNMI=2,1,0,2,1
```

And when I receive a sms I see the message `+CMTI: "SM",0` which means that I have the message in memory. However, the message stays there only for one second. If I enter the code to check the message after more than one second, it disappears, I have no idea why.

I verify the message with the following code:

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```

Have anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't really solved it. But as a workaround I'm using `gsmmodem` with python. More specifically, [this example](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem/blob/master/examples/sms_handler_demo.py) works fine for me, I receive some data and then I reply.

Comment: Thank you for the response, will have a look.  Bashing my head against this!

Comment: The `gsmmodem` library really worked nicely for me. I see the messages, I evaluate and reply depending on the commands sent by the phone. If that's your use case, I think it could be a fine alternative. I wish you luck in any case!

Comment: It worked for me as well!  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: It works because the python script notify you immediately when you receive a message. In my case, if I receive a message and a start the script after, there is no message to read, same problem as Gammu...

Comment: Sure, it's a workaround and not an answer =). The same comment was posted on the [github issue](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/issues/369#issuecomment-518577966), maybe it was also you, however the link is there for reference.